# Tensorflow Lite arm64 error: cannot convert ‘const int8x8_t?

Tags: c++, c, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow-lite

I tried building AARCH64 on ubuntu 16.04. I followed this guide(Native Compling) https://tensorflow.google.cn/lite/guide/build_arm64.

But I got this error. 
What is problem ?
Also I want try example on Orange Pi 3.
How to i can use the libtensorflow-lite.a file after build for arm64. I know Qt ide and c&c++.
Thank you.

```
In file included from ./tensorflow/lite/kernels/internal/optimized/depthwiseconv_uint8.h:22:0,
                 from tensorflow/lite/kernels/depthwise_conv.cc:29:
./tensorflow/lite/kernels/internal/optimized/depthwiseconv_uint8_3x3_filter.h: In static member function ‘static void tflite::optimized_ops::depthwise_conv::WorkspacePrefetchWrite<(tflite::DepthwiseConvImplementation)3>::Run(int8, int, int8*)’:
./tensorflow/lite/kernels/internal/optimized/depthwiseconv_uint8_3x3_filter.h:5782:71: note: use -flax-vector-conversions to permit conversions between vectors with differing element types or numbers of subparts
       vst1_lane_u32(reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(ptr), fill_data_vec, 0);
                                                                       ^
./tensorflow/lite/kernels/internal/optimized/depthwiseconv_uint8_3x3_filter.h:5782:71: error: cannot convert ‘const int8x8_t {aka const __vector(8) signed char}’ to ‘uint32x2_t {aka __vector(2) unsigned int}’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘void vst1_lane_u32(uint32_t*, uint32x2_t, int)’
./tensorflow/lite/kernels/internal/optimized/depthwiseconv_uint8_3x3_filter.h:5785:35: error: cannot convert ‘const int8x8_t {aka const __vector(8) signed char}’ to ‘uint32x2_t {aka __vector(2) unsigned int}’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘void vst1_lane_u32(uint32_t*, uint32x2_t, int)’
                   fill_data_vec, 0);
                                   ^
tensorflow/lite/tools/make/Makefile:225: recipe for target '/tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/aarch64_armv8-a/obj/tensorflow/lite/kernels/depthwise_conv.o' failed
make: *** [/tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/aarch64_armv8-a/obj/tensorflow/lite/kernels/depthwise_conv.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Comment: Does `-flax-vector-conversions` make any difference?

Comment: i don't know. i am new this subject. i only apply tensorflow lite guide. @doctorlove

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

After trying to solve the problem for hours, I think i found a solution for this:

Just add the "-flax-vector-conversions" parameter to the CXXFLAGS variable in the tensorflow/lite/tools/make/Makefile file.

For me it was in line 58:

```
CXXFLAGS := -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -flax-vector-conversions
```

The previous error is gone, but now I get an other error:

```
undefined reference to `shm_open'
```

After that, i added "-lrt" to tensorflow/lite/tools/make/targets/aarch64_makefile.inc

```
LIBS := \
-lstdc++ \
-lpthread \
-lm \
-ldl \
-lrt
```

and changed **BUILD_WITH_NNAPI** in the Makefile to **false**

The compile process worked.
I will test the TF library as soon as possible.

Comment: I still get a "**error: x29 cannot be used in asm here**" error.

Answer (score 1):

To build Tensorflow Lite for arm64, I modified:

> tensorflow/lite/tools/make/targets/aarch64_makefile.inc

by adding to both the CXXFLAGS and CFLAGS:

```
-flax-vector-conversions \
-fomit-frame-pointer \
```

which gives:

```
  CXXFLAGS += \
    -march=armv8-a \
    -funsafe-math-optimizations \
    -ftree-vectorize \
    -flax-vector-conversions \
    -fomit-frame-pointer \
    -fPIC

  CFLAGS += \
    -march=armv8-a \
    -funsafe-math-optimizations \
    -ftree-vectorize \
    -flax-vector-conversions \
    -fomit-frame-pointer \
    -fPIC
```

For me this got rid of the `error: cannot convert` as well as the `error: x29 cannot be used in asm here`.

I was then able to build `libtensorflow-lite.a`.

The command from the tutorial still gives me an error when building the sample apps: `undefined reference to flatbuffers::ClassicLocale::instance_`, the solution to this issue is described at

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28863

---

As a sidenote if you are trying to use the docker container from the guide:

https://tensorflow.google.cn/lite/guide/build_arm64

It recommends using `tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-devel` which according to docker hub is currently a 6 month old image (definitely not nightly):

https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags/?page=1

From that same link you can find a more recent `devel` container, in my case I used `devel-py3`

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into similar issue while building Tensorflow-1.14 on aarch64. I've used the changes suggested in this [PR](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/29515) and it has resolved this issue.

Resolve the following two issues on a linux_aarch64 system:

- prohibited conversions between vectors
- prohibited explicit use of frame pointer register x29 in asm

Add following case in the `def tflite_copts()` of the   `tensorflow/lite/build_def.bzl`

```
        str(Label("//tensorflow:linux_aarch64")): [
            "-flax-vector-conversions",
            "-fomit-frame-pointer",
        ],
```